# mongodb GROUP BY and COUNT an Array within Document

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**Given**:
A single document in collection. The Document contains an array. (i.e. Only one document entry exist in Collection)

**Expectation** :
perform group by on `city` and `print counts`

Sample Data:

```
{
name: "ABC Bank",
hospitalList: [
  {city: "Delhi", hspName: "EEE hospital"},
  {city: "Delhi", hspName: "FFF hospital"},
  {city: "Surat", hspName: "MMM hospital"},
  {city: "Noida", hspName: "GGG hospital"},
  {city: "Surat", hspName: "HHH hospital"},
  {city: "Surat", hspName: "NNN hospital"},
  {city: "Surat", hspName: "PPP hospital"},
]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Delhi - 2
Noida - 1
Surat - 3
```

Tried (but did NOT work)

```
$group: {
  _id: "hospitalList.city",
  count: { $sum: 1 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $match - to match the document bank name
- $unwind - split the array of
  object in own document
- $group - to group it by city then calculate
  count

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "ABC Bank"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$hospitalList"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$hospitalList.city",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Mongo playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ac7RkJd7vU9

as per expected output:
Mongo playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zeqB7P-BYmI